# Create Activity Feed in Laravel4 with polymorphic relations

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, polymorphic-associations, feed

i wanna create activity feed in laravel4, so i've done this with polymorphic relations where Feed model has item() function, here it's:

```
class Feed extends \Eloquent
{ 
    protected $table = 'feed'; 

    public function item() 
    { 
        return $this->morphTo(); 
    }
}
```

Then i added other relations for child models:

```
class UserStatus extends \Eloquent
{ 
    protected $table = 'user_status'; 

    public function feed() 
    { 
        return $this->morphMany('Feed', 'item'); 
    }
}

class Photo extends \Eloquent
{ 
    protected $table = 'photo'; 

    public function feed() 
    { 
        return $this->morphMany('Feed', 'item'); 
    }
}
```

But when i query activities of user it shows: 
**Class name must be a valid object or a string**

Here's my query in User model:

```
class User extends \Eloquent
{ 
    public function activities()
    { 
        return $this->hasMany('Feed', 'user_id')->with('item')->get();
    }
}
```

How can I get activity list (parent polymorphic model Feed) for user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs...

> Polymorphic relations allow a model to belong to more than one other
>   model, on a single association. For example, you might have a photo
>   model that belongs to either a staff model or an order model.

This allows a child object (eg. a photo or comment) to belong to more than one type of parent object. I think you're trying to do the opposite - a single parent with multiple types of children.